# How do you capture the last 10 minutes of the screen in a video?

Tags: video, desktop-recording

It's been a while since I think about this but I've never find a specific software for this type of demand.

What I would like to have is a program (preferably called in the terminal) which records and saves the screen in a buffer of adjustable length (e.g. 5, 10 minutes) everything past this length is just discarded similar to a chunk in a streaming process. That means at every tick the buffer is updated with the new recorded data and the oldest tick data is remove from the queue.
Then if I think something during these last 10 minutes is interesting I can press a chord/keyboard shortcut and it will save the current state of the buffer in a file (container) in a certain format (mp4).
This way I don't have to care about my computer memory to be full but still I can "capture the past" like if it was ever recorded.

The application domain is **very** wide, you could capture a clip of another stream, you could capture a music in a video or another stream, you could capture something you did on your computer (such as a screencast). In most case it would save you a lot of time because you probably encountered this situation where you had to search for passed information, or do a screencast you naturally did on your computer again..

Today I decide to ask the community if anybody knows such a software (again preferably that you can run in the terminal as a daemon or whatever). And if there is no in-one program that does the expected maybe you can share some ideas or methods you are or you'd be using to have the same effect (from installing several softwares, or using built-in features, etc). And nevertheless if you too crave to have this kind of program and you are a UNIX enthusiast, maybe we could open a GitHub project and try to build such a tool ourselves.

And sorry if this is a bit out of the scope, I'm ready to take the negative votes, but at least if this is the wrong place please direct me to one place where I'd have more ears (I'd delete this post).
Thanks in advance.